# How to inherit from class in same file when generating Django dynamic form

Tags: python, django

I'm fairly new to both Python and Django, and I'm in the process of building a small website. I've been experimenting with a dynamic form containing a `ModelChoiceField` constructed from a `QuerySet` that is determined by user input. The approach described [here](http://dougalmatthews.com/2009/Dec/16/nicer-dynamic-forms-in-django/) works well for me, but I run into trouble if I try to dynamically create a type that inherits from a class that I define within the same file. The reason I tried to do this was that I wanted to override the default form field order by setting the form's fields.keyOrder property.

This is how I tried to do it:

```
from django import forms

class AbstractForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AbstractForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.keyOrder = ['choices', 'second', 'third']

class ConcreteFormFactory(object):
    @staticmethod
    def generate(queryset):
        properties = {
            'second': forms.CharField(),
            'third': forms.CharField(),
            'choices': forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=queryset)
        }
        return type('ConcreteForm', (AbstractForm,), properties)
```

However, when I import ConcreteFormFactory in my view and attempt to call its generate() method, I get a NameError telling me that AbstractForm is not defined. I tried importing AbstractForm into the calling context, but to no avail. Since I wasn't able to get this approach to work, I accomplished my goal another way, but I would still like to understand the scoping issue here. How do I make my dynamic class aware of other classes defined in the same file where I create it? This is on Django 1.2 and Python 2.7.1 (I know that's a very old version of Django).

Comment: It should work like this. Can you post the traceback of that `NameError`?

Comment: Why have you set `generate(queryset)` to a static method? This may be the issue as static methods are called differently against the class instead of the instance object.

Comment: But @staticmethod shouldn't change how name lookups are done, right? Something like `class A(object): pass`, `class AFactory(object): @staticmethod def makeA(): return type('A', (A,), {})` works fine for me

Comment: Well that figures...I implemented my generic test code that I posted here and it worked. Then I refactored my real code to use this pattern and it worked. I must have had something else wrong. Sorry everybody!

Comment: But did you import it from another module? I didn't try that, but it just seems strange to me. I could be way off base here.

Comment: @Furbeenator yes, works if I call makeA from the same module, from the  shell (which is technically another module), from another module, ...

Answer (score 1):

I apologize--this code DOES work as intended. I refactored my real code to use this pattern, and this time it worked. I must have had something else wrong.

Comment: please close your question if it is not going to be helpful for others

Comment: Sorry, it won't let me.